# I want to add pagination in a criteria returned value

Tags: grails, pagination

```
params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 2, 100)
orders=OrderInfo.createCriteria().listDistinct()
```

For pagination, we need to pass the params to list eg. `Post.list(params)`. How do I pass it here? I tried but gives an error.

We also require total number which I get.
But I am not able to set params in

```
orders=OrderInfo.createCriteria().listDistinct()
```

Pls suggest the correct code

Comment: Moreover we get the total by Post.count(), I tried here by orders.size() its not taking this value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you pass the params as first parameter of the `list` method, you get an `PagedResultList` which has the method `getTotalCount()`. With this you could get total number of instances.

```
params.max = Math.min(params.max?.toInteger() ?: 25, 100)
params.offset = params.offset ? params.offset.toInteger() : 0

def orderInfoCriteria = OrderInfo.createCriteria()
def results = orderInfoCriteria.list(params) { // your criteria code ... }
log.debug "Getting ${results.size()} order infos of ${results.totalCount}"
```

Read the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for more information about critera.

Comment: Thankyou,I also wanted to know if these params can be passed in listDistinct? I tried it but it prompted error.

Comment: I have no experiences with `listDistinct` but there is a note in the docs that may help you: _"The listDistinct() method does not work well with the pagination options maxResult and firstResult. If you need distinct results with pagination, we currently recommend that you use HQL. You can find out more information from [this blog post](http://floledermann.blogspot.de/2007/10/solving-hibernate-criterias-distinct.html)."_

Comment: How will you do this in a service rather than the controller

Comment: There is no difference with controller and service - you just need to pass the params to the service. Or did I get your question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Grails Criteria Query and pagination params**

```
params.max = params?.max as Integer ?: 10
params.page = params?.page as Integer ?: 1
params.offset = (params.page - 1) * params.max
params.sort = params?.sort ?: "email"
params.order = params?.order ?: "asc"
params.filter = params?.filter ?: ""
params.packet = params?.packet ?: ""

def members = Member.createCriteria().list(params)
  {
    or
    {
      if(params.filter != ""){
        ilike("firstName", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        ilike("lastName", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        ilike("email", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        try {
          params.filter as Long
          eq("citizenId" , params.filter.toLong())
        }catch (e) {

        }
        ilike("mobile", "%" + params.filter + "%")
      }
    }
  }

def dataMembers = [:]
dataMembers.data = members
dataMembers.totalRecord = members.totalCount
render dataMembers as JSON
```

**Output**

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "firstName":name
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "firstName":name
    }
  ],
"totalRecord":5
}
```